# How to get MySql database queries log

Tags: mysql, profiling

I need a list of queries executed against my database on some shared server... is it possible to get that list without having admin rights?

any sort of profiling will help

Comment: Try to look in this direction https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-mysql.html `SET global general_log = 1;   
SET global log_output = 'table';`

Comment: However, changing any global option with `SET GLOBAL` requires admin rights.